# Meaning of some SerialCG logs

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm

I need help understanding some logs of the HotSpot Serial Collector.

Below are 5 different logs produced by my JVM (1.8). They are slightly cut for readability, but nothing important is removed.

```
1) [Full GC (Metadata GC Threshold)
        [Tenured: 0K->20760K(2796224K), 0.0516809 secs] 
            290882K->20760K(4054528K), 
        [Metaspace: 20914K->20914K(1069056K)], 0.0518074 secs] 

2) [GC (Allocation Failure) 
        [DefNew: 1118528K->35795K(1258304K), 0.0697424 secs] 
            1208983K->126251K(4054528K), 0.0698470 secs] 

3) [GC (Allocation Failure) 
        [DefNew: 1167292K->1167292K(1258304K), 0.0000172 secs] 
        [Tenured: 2587705K->2093117K(2796224K), 3.4401746 secs] 
            3754997K->2093117K(4054528K), 
        [Metaspace: 241446K->241446K(1296384K)], 3.4450897 secs] 

4) [GC (Allocation Failure) 417.013: 
        [DefNew (promotion failed) : 1234062K->1258304K(1258304K), 1.4832395 secs] 
        [Tenured: 2796224K->2275534K(2796224K), 4.1927802 secs] 
            3514367K->2275534K(4054528K), 
        [Metaspace: 226551K->226551K(1286144K)], 5.6762551 secs]  

5) [Full GC (Allocation Failure) 
        [Tenured: 2796224K->2424825K(2796224K), 4.8644173 secs] 
            4054528K->2424825K(4054528K), 
        [Metaspace: 226537K->226537K(1286144K)], 4.8645662 secs]
```

Questions:

1. What triggered Full GC in the log 1? It does not look like Metaspace is fully allocated. For information, it was server startup.
2. The log 2 is clear - Minor GC. It goes by [GC], unlike [Full GC]. But what happened in the log 3? It does not say that it is Full GC, but the Old generation was cleared. At the same time the Young gen is unchanged. As far as I know, old generation is cleared only during Full GC (like in the log 5). Interesting that Java Mission Control logged this event as Full GC.
3. What does "promotion failed" mean in the log 4?

I would appreciate any help. I wonder if there is any official document describing the GC logs (I personally didn't find any). Unfortunatelly, all articles on the Internet are limited to the two standard logs (When it comes to the Serial GC).

Answer (score 1):

> It does not look like Metaspace is fully allocated

It is not using the maximum size, however before growing the meta space it needs to do a collection to ensure it needs to.

> It does not say that it is Full GC, but the Old generation was cleared.

When only the tenured space is GC-ed it's called a major collection.

> What does "promotion failed" mean in the log 4?

There wasn't enough space in tenured space to promote all the objects to be promotoed from the new generation.

Comment: The point about promotion is clear now. Thank you. But as for the major GC. What triggered it in this case? There were still about 200mb available in the old gen. Defragmentation?

Comment: @AverageJoe possibly. Large objects are allocated in the tenured space directly. If there is not enough continuous space left for a big allocation it will trigger a collection.